# When one thread executes java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0, other threads is locked

Tags: java, tomcat

```
"http-apr-80-exec-83" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000011abf000 nid=0x1a8c runnable [0x000000002568c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2571)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2581)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2587)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1429)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1261)
    - locked <0x00000007800129a0> (a com.sun.beans.WeakCache)
    at java.beans.Introspector.internalFindMethod(Introspector.java:1290)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1361)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1341)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:227)
    - locked <0x000000078e17a548> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getReadMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1256)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1325)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at com.xttb.ptf.model.DAOSupport.insertItems(DAOSupport.java:534)
    at com.xttb.ptf.model.DAOSupport.insertItem(DAOSupport.java:478)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService.loginPost(LoginService.java:236)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$20a9cdb3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ccccc9b.loginPost(<generated>)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doLoginService(SSOLoginController.java:172)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doSSOLoginPost(SSOLoginController.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor736.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at com.xttb.ptf.AppDispatcher.doService(AppDispatcher.java:21)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.SSOSourceControlHandler.doChain(SSOSourceControlHandler.java:75)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.FilterHandler.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:49)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.controller.SSORequestController.doFilter(SSORequestController.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.coyote.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
    - locked <0x00000007d5fa7d88> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AprSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c54b9f60> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


    "http-apr-80-exec-77" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000111ae800 nid=0x1960 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002513d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1258)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007800129a0> (a com.sun.beans.WeakCache)
    at java.beans.Introspector.internalFindMethod(Introspector.java:1290)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1361)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:296)
    - locked <0x000000078e154738> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:970)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:456)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:41)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:30)
    at com.xttb.ptf.model.DAOSupport.getItemsBySql(DAOSupport.java:230)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService.loginUser(LoginService.java:1089)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService.loginPost(LoginService.java:213)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$20a9cdb3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ccccc9b.loginPost(<generated>)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doLoginService(SSOLoginController.java:172)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doSSOLoginPost(SSOLoginController.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor736.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at com.xttb.ptf.AppDispatcher.doService(AppDispatcher.java:21)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.SSOSourceControlHandler.doChain(SSOSourceControlHandler.java:75)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.FilterHandler.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:49)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.controller.SSORequestController.doFilter(SSORequestController.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.coyote.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
    - locked <0x00000007d65e5e08> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AprSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c54282c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


    "http-apr-80-exec-75" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000011aba800 nid=0x1cd8 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000024d9d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1258)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007800129a0> (a com.sun.beans.WeakCache)
    at java.beans.Introspector.internalFindMethod(Introspector.java:1290)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1361)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:296)
    - locked <0x000000078e312e68> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:970)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:456)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:41)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:30)
    at com.xttb.ptf.model.DAOSupport.getItemsBySql(DAOSupport.java:230)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.handlers.User2Organ.getAccountsByempcode(User2Organ.java:70)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.handlers.SSOLoginImpl.postHandler(SSOLoginImpl.java:52)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.handlers.SSOSessionImpl.postHandler(SSOSessionImpl.java:73)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.handlers.SSOJjtServerSecurityImpl.postHandler(SSOJjtServerSecurityImpl.java:42)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.handlers.SSOServerSecurityImpl.postHandler(SSOServerSecurityImpl.java:47)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.ThreadRequestManager.createContext(ThreadRequestManager.java:35)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.ThreadRequestManager.getSSORequest(ThreadRequestManager.java:27)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.FilterHandler.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:38)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.controller.SSORequestController.doFilter(SSORequestController.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.coyote.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
    - locked <0x00000007d7e2df90> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AprSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c540e9e0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


    "http-apr-80-exec-67" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000151be800 nid=0xf70 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002388c000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1258)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007800129a0> (a com.sun.beans.WeakCache)
    at java.beans.Introspector.internalFindMethod(Introspector.java:1290)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1361)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:296)
    - locked <0x000000078e34e640> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:970)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:456)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:41)
    at com.xttb.ptf.util.DBUtil.buildVO(DBUtil.java:30)
    at com.xttb.ptf.model.DAOSupport.getItemBySql(DAOSupport.java:180)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService.loginUser(LoginService.java:915)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService.loginPost(LoginService.java:213)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$20a9cdb3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.xttb.ptf.LoginService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ccccc9b.loginPost(<generated>)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doLoginService(SSOLoginController.java:172)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.login.SSOLoginController.doSSOLoginPost(SSOLoginController.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor736.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at com.xttb.ptf.AppDispatcher.doService(AppDispatcher.java:21)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.SSOSourceControlHandler.doChain(SSOSourceControlHandler.java:75)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.FilterHandler.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:49)
    at com.xttb.ptf.sso.controller.SSORequestController.doFilter(SSORequestController.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xttb.ptf.coyote.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
    - locked <0x00000007d7dea7b8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AprSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007c52da638> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

### ---------------------------------------------------------

---

Configuration: jdk1.7, Tomcat-7.0.94
Why is http-apr-80-exec-83 ava.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method) always running?

I am a thread beginner please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JGdS.png)

Comment: Since we can't see your code, or the full call stack, it's not possible for us to answer that.

Comment: If you're a beginner in Java, why are you running on ancient code (Java 7, Tomcat 7)?

Comment: For other reasons I cannot upload the complete dump file, I mean http-apr-80-exec-83 has been executed for a long time. All requests because it is in the blocked state. Eventually the service is stopped. The operating system is windows server.

Comment: Hi Andrew I have uploaded it, please help analyze it.

Comment: *"Why is http-apr-80-exec-83 ava.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method) always running?"* Because **your** `DAOSupport` class keeps calling [`PropertyUtils.getProperty()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-), which is not a fast method, since it has to fully analyze the class(es) in question **every time** (maybe even for each iteration of a loop, perhaps?)

Comment: See answer here for potential solution: [PropertyUtils performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2228542/5221149)

Comment: Landed here through a Google search. I have a production JVM (taken off the load balancer for investigation) stuck at 200% CPU spin, one thread is stuck on a call to `PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod` and another on `PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod`. JDK 17. Super weird!